# Can subclass inline a pure virtual method that is not inline in the base?

Tags: c++, virtual

As I understand it, the compiler can inline a virtual function call when it knows at compile time what the type of the object will be at runtime ([C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/value-vs-ref-semantics.html#faq-31.6)).

What happens, however, when one is implementing a pure virtual method from a base class? Do the same rules apply? Will the following function call be inlined?

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;

    virtual void callPrint()
    {
        print(); // will this be inline?
    }
};

class child : public base
{
public:
    void print() { cout << "hello\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    child c;
    c.callPrint();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think my original example code was actually a poor representation of what I wanted to ask. I've updated the code, but the question remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is of course "it depends", but in principle there's no obstruction to optimization. In fact, you're not even doing anything polymorphic here, so this is really straight-forward.

The question would be more interesting if you had code like this:

```
child c;
base & b = c;
b.print();
```

The point is that the compiler knows at this point what the ultimate target of the dynamic dispatch will be (namly `child::print()`), so this is eligible for optimization. (There are two separate opportunities for optimization, of course: one by avoiding the dynamic dispatch, and one coming from having the function body of the target visible in the TU.)

Comment: You're right, and in fact, that was the crux of what I wanted to find out. I've updated the code snippet to reflect this.

Answer (score 10):

The compiler is never *required* to inline a function call. In this case, it is *permitted* to inline the function call, because it knows the concrete type of `c` (since it is not indirected through a pointer or reference, the compiler can see where it was allocated as a `child`). As such, the compiler knows which implementation of `print()` is used, and can choose not to perform vtable indirection, and further choose to inline the implementation of the function.

However, the compiler is also free to *not* inline it; it might insert a direct call to `child::print()`, or indirect through the vtable, if it decides to do so.

These optimizations in general boil down to the 'as-if' rule - the compiler must behave *as-if* it was doing a full vtable indirect - this means that the *result* must be the same, but the compiler can choose a different method of achieving the result if the result is the same. This includes inlining, etc.

Comment: I enjoy your personification of the compiler.

Comment: +1 `inline` is a compiler hint. At the end of the day the compiler will do what it thinks is best and thank goodness for that!

Comment: @GWW, it's best to think of it this way, unless you're actually writing the compiler, in which case you're doing the choosing :)

Comment: I realized the code snippet was a poor representation of what I **actually** wanted to know. While this is an answer worthy of an upvote, I would appreciate you taking a look at the updated code and offering some comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a couple of rules you should be aware of:

1) The compiler is never forced to inline - even using the directive or defining a method in the header.

2) Polymorphism MUST ALWAYS WORK. This means that the compiler will prefer calling the function via the vftable rather than inlining it when the possibility of dynamic calls exists.